# can Firebase work for android app and for web app simultaneously

Tags: android, firebase, web-applications

I am new in Android development can anyone tell me How Firebase help to convert web app to Android App. I have few web app and it has login, registration and many form. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Can Firebase work for android app and for web app simultaneously?

If you create both a web and an Android version of an app, both can access the same Firebase project. But Firebase doesn't automatically convert the code for the apps or anything magical like that.